# Update object value within foreach loop

Tags: php

I would like to loop through the contents of a query object update certain values and return the object.

```
function clearAllIds($queryObject)
{ 
   foreach($queryObject->result() as $row)
 {
  $row->id = 0;
 }
return $queryObject
}
```

In this example I would like to zero out all of the ID values. How can I accomplish this within the foreach loop?

Please excuse the formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This entirely depends on what the class of your query object is, and whether or not you'll be able to [Pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Assuming your `$queryObject->result()` can be delivered in a write-context, you could preface the `$row` with an ampersand to pass it by reference, like so:

```
foreach($queryObject->result() as &$row)
{
    $row->id = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearAllIds($queryObject)
{ 
   foreach($queryObject->result() as &$row)
   {
     $row->id = 0;
   }
   return $queryObject
}
```

Use the & operator to get $row as a reference.

Edit: This will work if $queryObject is an array. You should probably do

```
$data = $queryObject->result();
foreach($data as &$row) { ... }
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim_spaces($object)
        {       
            foreach (get_object_vars($object) as $property=> $value) 
                {
                    $object->$property=trim($value);
                }
         }
```

//no need to return object as they are passed by reference by default

Comment: Add a description to your ans as well, explaining it.